# Different authentication methods for MVC Controllers and WebAPI (Cookies+Bearer) using Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a web application that implements both MVC controllers and webapi controllers. This web application uses Microsoft account authentication based on external cookies.

Now I want to query the webapi from a native (desktop) application using MSAL to authenticate the users against the Microsoft identity platform.

I tried to do this adding the following code to use bearer authentication: `app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                        }
                    });`

I can authenticate the client through the PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive method and use the resulting AccessToken for compounding the Authorization header, but the webapp responds with a 401 error code.

```
 request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
 var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

In summary, the goal is not use both cookies and bearer authentication at the same time, but to have a unique web application using MVC that:

- Could serve web pages with an authorization mechanism
- Could publish a REST based API (through WebAPI) using the same authorization mechanism, that:

  1. Authenticates against Microsoft Azure AD accounts
  2. Could be consumed by Desktop clients
  3. Could be consumed by the previous web app pages for displaying dynamic content.